# Using the ion_auth login process and using a templated process to render the login process

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm a new kid with CI and ion_auth and have both running correctly. I have also created a view/template of a view/template/header and view/template/footer on another page ('welcome') that is a part of a fairly complex html5 responsive template with all my assets in a directory called assets/html5templateV1/css etc.

The question is what is the best approach of using the views/auth/login.php file with the template so I have

1. A nice looking login page /failed login / request pwd page etc.
2. The login page uses a templated HTML layout approach (mine is probably incorrect)
3. Updates to ion_auth can be fairly easily installed
4. The next person along doesn't say "WT?" and start pulling hair out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use ion_auth views or controllers. they are just for reference. we have to use their function as they have define in model for `login/logout/register` etc... just simply put his `model,library and config file to the respective folder of codeigniter in your project` and just use their function as they have shown in demo